# Select individual word in vsc

Tags: visual-studio-code, selection

anyone knows how to select individual words in vsc? Like the ctrl + select keyboard shortcut in microsoft word.
[Video example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yDhvWCSHCxzeuRC2iC8qf_KAiVfbJYu1/view?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: have you tried `Ctrl+D`

Comment: Ctrl+D only allows me to select similar words

Comment: try `Alt+Double_click`, `Alt` is the MultiCursor modifier, you might have changed it

Comment: Or `Alt+Click` the separate words and then `Ctrl+D`

Comment: The video is not accessible. I suggest inlining a GIF instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question was given by rioV8 who suggested me to try using Alt+Double_Click.